# I want all photos that are texted to a certain phone number to be uploaded to my server and shown on page

Tags: php, file-upload, web, photo, tumblr

Basically, I've been playing with photography lately and think it would be cool if you could possibly send a photo to a phone number (or at worst case email address) and have it automatically uploaded to a tumblr page (anyone could have access to it if they had the number or email).  Does anyone know if there is a script I could start off with this?  I'm familiar with PHP, HTML, MYSQL, etc...I just don't have the slightest clue where to begin with this one. If you have **ANY** insight what so ever it would be greatly appreciated and maybe i'll give you some server space. Thanks

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: With emails, sure, quite doable, with mms, no thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

1. MMS seems to be a solution.
2. But for automatic uploading, you'll need to design apps corresponding to those platforms (android, ios, symbian etc.) to go through the messages and pick up the attachments and upload on tumblr.
3. As far as access is concerned, I guess you're saying that someone who knows that phone-number might be able to search it up on tumblr.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Worst case:

> **Can I post to my blog via email?**
> Yup!

— http://www.tumblr.com/docs/email_publishing

And yes, even [photo posts](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing#photo):

> **How do I send a Photo post?**
>
> 1. Attach a photo to the email.
> 2. Write a caption in the subject line.